# Casperjs doesn't always execute some steps

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

There's some strange behavior with Casperjs. When i execute my code, the last `then`step doesn't always get called. I really don't know why.

The code

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug'
});

 login = 'user';
 password = 'password';
 baseURL = 'http://fr.bazarchic.com';

function getHomepageLinks() {
    console.log('hello');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.label_big a'), function(e) {
        return e.getAttribute('href');
    });
}

casper.start(baseURL, function(){
    this.fill('form[action="/login/"]', {
    'email' : login,
    'pass' : password
    }, true)
});

casper.then(function() {
    ventesLinks = this.evaluate(getHomepageLinks);

});

casper.then(function() {
    this.echo(ventesLinks);
    this.eachThen(ventesLinks, function(response){
        this.echo(response.data);
    })
})



casper.run(function() {

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to split those 2 steps, then you should use waitFor instead of then() for the last one:

```
casper.waitFor(function check() {
    return ventesLinks.length > 0;
}, function then() {
    this.echo(ventesLinks);
    this.eachThen(ventesLinks, function(response){
        this.echo(response.data);
    });
});
```